# How to express your GPA along with the name of your university?

Tags: word-usage, formal-language

When I'm talking about my academic background, If I want to mention the level of my GPA (not the exact number), how can I do so?
I was graduated in (or at) the university of XYZ with the GPA of B (or B GPA), (or B level GPA), (or the GPA of (the) level B). If any of them is correct please suggest me the best formal one.

Comment: GPA's are either a 3.0 or 4.0, depending on the college. Also, we don't say; I was graduated. We say: "I graduated from Georgetown University in [year] with a 4.00 GPA". If your GPA is 3.00 or 4.00, you have a straight As. If you are coming from another country, don't try to find equivalences. In the states, if you do have all straight A/s, you usually are awarded other honors like Magna Cum Laude or Summa Cum Laude.

Comment: Sasan, are you planning to react? I just wonder....

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as an American: The term "GPA" is normally understood to mean a number. You could round off, but "I had a GPA of B" sounds incongruous to me, like saying "My favorite color is 7".

That said, the normal way to say this in the US is, "I graduated from Fwacbar University with a GPA of 3.2". Or if you got an honors designation, to say, "I graduated from Fwacbar University magna cum laude".

If there's some reason why you really want to give a letter, I suppose you could say, "... with a GPA of B". As I say, I think most Americans would think that was a very odd way to say it but they'd understand what you meant. It would be more accurate to say "... with a GPA in the B range" or something of that sort. But that sounds to me like you're trying to hide something. Like why do say you're going to tell me your GPA but then carefully dance around actually telling me? If you're trying to convey your education to someone from another country with a different grading system, you might say, "... with a GPA that corresponds to Orange [or whatever of course] in your grading system".

Comment: It is always a number. Never a grade.  a GPA of B, simply does not work. We say: with a GPA of 3.8, for example, Or a 3.8 GPA. The fact you even suggest this tells me you did not attend an American college. If your school, uses a 4.00 GPA, a 4.00 equals straight A's but then you would not say it because everyone knows that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest expression, if you are in a country that uses letters for grades (so that everyone knows that GPA levels are represented by letters A,B, C etc)

> I graduated from {name of university} with a 'B'.

Note that "graduate" is used as an active verb here (not I was graduated). Also note that in an international context "with a B" could mean very little to an employer who is not familiar with your education system.

Comment: You don't graduate with a grade. It is hoped you take more than one course. I graduated from x with a B average or a B+ average. That means more than a single course. You have an average level of grades.

Comment: That is true in the USA.  But perhaps not true in the OP's country. Perhaps there you do a a letter grade with your degree.  In the UK you get a number grade: 1st, 2:1, 2:2 or 3rd. Hence my last sentence.

Comment: It does not matter what his country is. You have to use what the target country uses or adapt sensibly. Mixing GPA and grades is not sensible. I have done a lot of degree/diploma and transcript work, so I know this area very well.

Comment: Yes,  that is what I said.  "In an international context 'with a B' could mean very little to an employer"